# Basic questions about git checkout -b

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git and github and have this scenario:

1. I have a repo in github
2. I've cloned locally
3. I've created a new branch from my CLI by doing:

`git checkout -b new_branch`

- **Question A:** 
  I've found out that this new_branch branch hasn't been created on my github project. Is this because I'm supposed to upload it?
- **Question B**
  when a do a git log I get: commit 9a0b7a..truncated (HEAD -> new_branch, master). Am I on new_branch, right? if so, why it says master as well?
- **Question C:**
  I tried doing git merge so that my local changes are being pushed but got this: fatal: No remote for the current branch. So, this is because my new_branch still doesn't exist on github. What should I do to make it appear on github now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Yes, with the [`push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) command.

B) Yes, it means that this commit is where the branch `new_branch` is pointing at, which is also the case for `master` since you didn't already commit on this branch, it's expected that they're "at the same point" for now.

It also means that `new_branch` is checked out since `HEAD` points to it.

C) It's not because the branch doesn't exist on remote, it's because your *local* branch doesn't have yet somewhere to send it (what's called an upstream branch). You could set it with the [`-u`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--u) flag of the `push` command.